# /testfor problem (Snapshot 16w05a)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/testfor @a[x=1016,y=56,z=1016,dx=984,dy=57,dz=984]
```

When I run this command in a command block, the output is blank, but I verified all tags but I can't find the problem

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? Do you get a specific error? Can you include that?

Comment: It don't say anything (I'm in a 1.9 Snapshot and there is no output in the command block or in the chat)

Comment: It just don't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a command block shows no output, this can be caused by a target selector that is *capable* of obtaining multiple targets (`@a` is capable so long as `c=1` is not used) but results in no targets found.

The `dx`, `dy`, and `dz` parameters are **not** a second set of coordinates. They are instead the number of blocks it takes to get from `x`, `y`, `z` to the other corner. You will need to change the values to adhere to this.

```
/testfor @a[x=1016,y=56,z=1016,dx=-32,dy=1,dz=-32]
```

Comment: THANKS !!!!! It works, it was due to the dx, dy and dz tags because I didn't know that they aren't a set of coordinates